# can anyone tell me why the fibonacci function does not work?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I want to have it add every once a parameter it has not yet found to the map, but when I try numbers higher than 47 it gives me negative numbers, clearly impossible

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;


//memoization
map<unsigned int, unsigned int> memo;
map<unsigned int, unsigned int>::iterator it;
int fibonacci(int n)
{   
    it = memo.find(n);
    if (it != memo.end())
    {
        cout << it->first<<endl;
        return memo.at(n);
    }
    if (n <= 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    memo.insert({ n, fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2) });
    cout << "----"<<n<<endl;
    return memo.at(n);
}
int main()
{
    cout<<fibonacci(48);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the result of FIBO(40) and the maximum value `unsigned int` can hold with a pocket calculator?

Comment: What's "igni"??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A pocket calculator? I realise passive-aggressive versions of "you should have done x, y, z simple-to-me thing first" comments are all the rage, but, really, a pocket calculator?? We're dumbing it down to _that_ level?

Comment: sorry i meant every @AsteroidsWithWings

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the phrase _"I want to have it add every once a parameter it has not yet found to the map,"_.

Comment: ***47 it gives me negative numbers, clearly impossible*** If numbers are too big they will overflow. Some common implementations an int is 32 bits and others its 64.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings 
i mean i have to add the number in the map only if i haven't found it yet, sorry for my bad english

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I don't grasp where you see _passive aggressiveness_ in my comment? It's just a question for proof. Pocket calculators are usually designed to calculate with bigger numbers than a programming language offers with standard CPU friendly types. No _dumbing down_ intended there. Sorry if someone reads something else.

Comment: I usually just google and find the following which has the first 300 Fibonacci numbers: [http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Also there's a good chance, that a good, modern scientific pocket calculator aleady offers a _`FIBO(x)`_ function.

Comment: @drescherjm and now Google will start showing you math-based ads.

Comment: Just as a note, in this case, you can mark the normal recursive fib function as constexpr, and the compiler will do the memorization for you. And it will tell you at wich point you are overflowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's take care of the negative numbers. Comments above explained that you have an overflow of the 32-bit int.

However, you could stretch your code a bit further would you not convert an unsigned int you calculate to a `signed` one you return from that function.

The solution is to use larger types, like `unsigned long long int`, AKA `uint64_t`

**UPDATE**

There are a few things sub-optimal in accepted answer.

1. As I noted in a comment there, the code is searching the map twice: `it = memo.find(n);` and `memo[n];`; should just return `it->second;`
2. There is no need for the key in that map to be 64-bit wide; 32 bit is enough to overflow 64-bit Fibonacci.
3. As the order of map keys is not important (you only do insert / lookup), the `unordered_map` will perform better (constant time instead of logarithmic).
4. You may notice that the `memo` is filled in order, and accessed by the index. Much better container here will be a `vector` with a "free" insert and lookup.
5. The calling function should NOT fill in `memo`, as it's not its business.

Here is my version:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//memoization
static std::vector<uint64_t> memo = { 0, 0, 1 };
uint64_t fibonacci(unsigned int n) {
  if (n < memo.size())
    return memo[n];

  memo.push_back(fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2));
  return memo[n];
}
int main() {
  std::cout << fibonacci(32'000);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much i tried come you advised me and it works

Comment: Then you should accept the answer... if you are satisfied with the solution

Answer (score 1):

> but when I try numbers higher than 47 it gives me negative numbers,
> clearly impossible

unsigned int size is {0 to 4,294,967,295}, 48th Fibonacci is 4,807,526,976

Fixed code

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;


//memoization
map<int64_t , int64_t> memo;
map<int64_t , int64_t>::iterator it;
int64_t fibonacci(int64_t n) {
    it = memo.find(n);
    if (it != memo.end()) {
        return it->second;;
    }
    memo.insert({n, fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)});
    return memo[n];
}
int main() {
    memo.insert({0, 0});
    memo.insert({1, 1});
    memo.insert({2, 1});
    cout << fibonacci(50);
}
```

Comment: Side note: Unsigned `int` can be as small at 16 bit (0-65535) and as large as (but no larger than) `long`. And `long` can be any size from 32 bits to the same size as `long long`. And `long long` is at least 64 bits and (at this time) has no specified maximum.  There is no guaranteed fixed size, just the minimum. When you need guarantees you need to use [fixed width integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) looted from C.

Comment: You are searching your map twice: `it = memo.find(n);` and `memo[n];`; should just return `it->second;`